# Why can my VB.NET User Control not instantiate an ObjectContext?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, user-controls

I have the following lines of code as a test user control. When the project is built, and I drag this user control onto a form, I get an error dialogue to the effect that EF can't find the connection string for the context. Yet when I use the same variable in a form, all is well. It seems the user control is using a different context within which to look for the connection string than the usual app.config.

```
Public Class InvoiceWorkOrderSearch
    Private _dataHelper As WorkOrderData = New WorkOrderData()
End Class
```

Comment: Is the usercontrol in a separate project from the one which you are adding it to?

Comment: Separate UI and data layer. Contexts in user controls is bad.

Comment: @GertArnold The context is in the BO layer, but the form instantiates a BO helper, which instantiates the context. This is an urgent first draft, so I don't want to clutter things with DI at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Design time?

You can avoid this be only instancing the object if the control is in runtime mode.

The build in property to check for desing time (`Me.DesignMode`) is poor since it only tells you if you are currently designing the control itself. It returs false if you drop the usercontrol on a form.

You can use this code to check for designtime: http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/designmode-workaround-windows-forms-SID299.aspx

```
Public Class InvoiceWorkOrderSearch
    Private _dataHelper As WorkOrderData

    Public Sub New()
        If IsDesignMode(me) = False Then
            _dataHelper = New WorkOrderData()
        End If
    End Sub()
End Class
```

Comment: Ive used something very similar to this answer, but i;ve also used the #If Debug #else #EndIf for other scenarios... the IsDesignMode was great for drag/drop controls.

Comment: you can't use the #Debug directive for that because if you ever deploy a debug build this will evaluate to true.

Comment: This solved what would have been a myriad other related problems as well. Thanks.